# Elemento con position fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy realizando el desarrollo de una página web y me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

Quiero poner un menú en el lateral izquierdo de mi página y que se desplace cuando lo haga el scroll. Hasta ahí todo bien, el problema es que para situar ese menú en el lateral izquierdo tengo que usar un `position:relative`, por lo que si uso un `position:fixed` el menú se me coloca en su lugar original de la página.

Quisiera saber si existe alguna función en js o jquery o alguna propiedad de css para identificar el momento en el que el menú tiene que cambiar a position:fixed. 
Adjunto código

Código CSS:

```
.lateral{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

Este es el código para que el menú se situe en la posición que quiero, no obstante cuando cambio a `position:fixed` vuelve a su posición original de la página, sobrepuesto sobre otros elemento.

Código HTML

```
<aside class="lateral">
            <div class="contenedor" style="padding-top: 5%;" >
                <div class="temas">
                    <h3>Temáticas</h3>
                    <nav>
                        <a href="#">Psicología social</a>
                        <a href="#">Psicología clínica y de la salud</a>
                        <a href="#">Neuropsicologia</a>
                        <a href="#">Psicología de la educación y del desarrollo</a>
                        <a href="#">Psicología de las organizaciones</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="artPublicados">
                    <!-- MENÚ DESPLEGABLE DE ARTICULOS PUBLICADOS -->
                    <h3>Artículos publicados</h3>
                        <nav id="menu">
                            <a href=#>Art1</a>
                            <a href=#>Art2</a>
                            <a href=#>Art3</a>
                        </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- LATERAL IZQUEIRDO -->
        </aside>
```

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour], si puediera agregar lo que llevas al momento sería mas fácil ayudarte

Comment: He añadido código para que se entienda mejor

Comment: stringmanolo.ml/dhunter en el botón blanco tiene un menú. Quieres hacer algo así pero que salga por la izquierda o qué? No te entendí nada xD
Intenta explicarte mejor. No estamos en tu cerebro para saber exactamente lo que intentas hacer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se me hace un tanto enredada la forma en que maquetas el resultado que deseas obtener, propongo lo siguiente y espero se adapte a tus necesidades.

- Lo primero es que si deseas que el menú se mueva conforme haces *scroll* y posterior quede en su posición original, entonces considero sería mas óptimo usar `position: sticky;`
- Posterior si deseas que el menú aparezca al costado izquierdo y a lado el texto de relleno entonces tal vez sería mas útil considerar el uso de *flexbox* pues por defecto este modelo de cajas alineará los elementos en el *main axis* o el eje x; dado eso entonces primero aparecerá el menú y a un costado los textos del resto del cuerpo de tu página
- A la `position` que declares le debemos indicar desde donde empezará el *scroll* y en este caso le indicamos `top: 0;`

Lo demás que coloco son solo adornos visuales para tratar de representar mejor el resultado del ejemplo:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Document</title>
      <style>
        main {
          display: flex;
        }
        .menu-lista {
          background-color: crimson;  
          position: sticky;
          top: 0;
          margin-top: 0;
          margin-right: 10px;
          min-width: 100%;
          padding-left: 10px;
        }
        .menu-lista__elemento {
          list-style: none;
        }
        h1 {
          margin: 0;
          background-color: tomato;
        }
        .menu {
          margin-right: 15px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <main>
        <nav class="menu">
          <ul class="menu-lista">
            <li class="menu-lista__elemento">Elemento 1</li>
            <li class="menu-lista__elemento">Elemento 2</li>
            <li class="menu-lista__elemento">Elemento 3</li>
            <li class="menu-lista__elemento">Elemento 4</li>
            <li class="menu-lista__elemento">Elemento 5</li>
            <li class="menu-lista__elemento">Elemento 6</li>
            <li class="menu-lista__elemento">Elemento 7</li>
            <li class="menu-lista__elemento">Elemento 8</li>
            <li class="menu-lista__elemento">Elemento 9</li>
            <li class="menu-lista__elemento">Elemento 10</li>
            <li class="menu-lista__elemento">Elemento 11</li>
            <li class="menu-lista__elemento">Elemento 12</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <section>
          <h1>Mira el sorprendente párrafo de abajo</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate odio sed, sint aspernatur nulla suscipit magni fugit inventore, minima! Placeat doloribus, dicta laborum corrupti minus dolor eum unde ducimus maiores!</p>
    
        </section>
      </main>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Referencias**

- [Soporte en navegadores a `sticky`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_position_sticky)